# Listener on session attribute change in servlet

Tags: java, session, servlets, tomcat8

I'm trying to find out if Tomcat has a listener that lets you know exactly when the session object has been updated.  From background research, it appears that a session object doesn't automatically get updated the moment an attribute changes, but rather at some indeterminate time (i.e. something like polling behind the scenes that checks if any session attribute values have changed since the last poll - and this goes on every XYZ (milli)seconds).

Thanks guys.

Comment: Do you mean detecting the change client-side or server-side?

Comment: I mean detecting the change server-side.

So, if I set an attribute like this:

    session.setAttribute("name", "Jane");

Then, 40 lines down, I set the attribute again:

    session.setAttribute("name", "John");

Is there any way I can have a 'listener' set on it that lets me know that's happened?  For instance, if I wanted to *RIGHT AWAY* update the value in a database session table.  Obviously, the HttpSessionAttributeListener is limited in the sense that it doesn't know the *NEW* value, only the *OLD* value.  The listener would need to be on the SESSION object itself.

Comment: `httpSessionAttributeListener.getValue()` returns the old value, but `httpSessionAttributeListener.getSession().getAttribute(...)` should get the new value.

Comment: You could always decorate the `HttpSession` in a `Filter` out front and intercept the changes. Also, why do you need to update in the database on *each* change? Why not save them up and do them in a single transaction?

Comment: @David - thanks for the responses.

So I should have mentioned the pre-requisite(s).  The classes are created using JAXB through XSD schemas.  Can these schemas be made to do what your first response (of two follow-ups) says to do to get the most up-to-date value?  That would require implementing and overriding the methods in a very unique, possibly deviant-from-the-standard way.

Comment: Which classes were generated from XSD schemas?

Comment: Our custom classes, let's call them User, Blog, Post, etc.  So, my original code example [setAttribute on a FIELD (such as name) is probably a bad example...]!
----
Blog blog = new Blog();
request.setAttribute("blog", blog);
// more code ...
Blog blog2 = new Blog();
request.setAttribute("blog", blog2);
---

The attribute **BLOG** [better to understand, I hope...it's based off the CLASS Blog] is updated.   

Since our Blog class frequently changes, we don't write code for that class, but generate it from a schema.

Does that make sense?  Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: I'm not sure how linking against a generated class rather than one you wrote by hand would change the ability to intercept changes to the session. You'll still need to persist instances of the generated classes, but that's in another layer. tl;dr: it should work fine.